# How to import file GeoJSON in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geojson

I need to import a GeoJSON file into GEE. I converted a shapefile in GeoJSON in QGIS, and I would like to import this GeoJSON file into GEE. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the geojson as plaintext in a separate script, and then call it inside your main script as a geometry.

```
var geometry = require('users/repo/path:geojson').getGeometry();
```

See explanation here https://medium.com/@HarelDan/gee-plaintext-geometry-assets-b85712bcd142

Answer (score 2):

Earth Engine accepts table data import from .csv and Shapefile. So instead of your GeoJSON, you could upload the .shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj of the Shapefile.

[image: Asset - Table Upload]

Comment: Hi @Philipp Gärtner. I need work with GeoJSON only

Answer (score 2):

You can use [geemap](https://geemap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html?highlight=geojson#features) for this, if you're comfortable using the Python API. It has a built-in function to convert GeoJSON to EE objects: `geojson_to_ee`.

```
import geemap
import ee
ee.Initialize()
ee_object = geemap.geojson_to_ee(geojson_file_path)

exportTask = ee.batch.Export.table.toAsset(
    collection = ee_object,
    description = 'description',
    assetId = 'users/username/folderName'
)
exportTask.start()
```

Comment: hi @hooge048 this geemap is a software? I have to instal it?

Comment: See this [link](https://geemap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html?highlight=geojson#installation). You could, for example, run `pip install geemap`

Comment: in the GEE itself?